# How to display the pdf file in pdf view that retrieve from firebase instead of just downloading the pdf file in Android Studio?

Tags: android, firebase, pdf

I'm making an app that lets the user upload the pdf file in the firebase. I can successfully retrieve the pdf file from firebase but now I want to let the user view the pdf file in the application instead of downloading the pdf file.

This is a java of how I retrieve the pdf file from firebase:

```
public class RetrievePDF extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    List<putPDF> uploadedPDF;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_retrieve_pdf);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        uploadedPDF= new ArrayList<>();


        retrievePDFFiles();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {
                putPDF putPDF = uploadedPDF.get(i);

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setType("application/pdf");
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(putPDF.getUrl()));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        
    }

    private void retrievePDFFiles() {

        databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploadPDF");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    putPDF putPDF= ds.getValue(com.example.uploadpdf.putPDF.class);
                    uploadedPDF.add(putPDF);

                }

                String[] uploadsName=new String[uploadedPDF.size()];

                for(int i=0;i<uploadsName.length;i++){
                    uploadsName[i]= uploadedPDF.get(i).getName();
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, uploadsName){

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

                        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                        TextView textView=(TextView) view
                                .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

                        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        textView.setTextSize(20);
                        return view;
                     }
                };

                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

This is my XML file:

And I want to let the display the pdf in a view with image and text 3 in 1 row. How can I display all pdf files in view like this  [example view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuCzB.png)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RetrievePDF">

<!-- Header aligned to top -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:text="Header title"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="114dp"
        android:layout_height="99dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@color/teal_700"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="105dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Footer aligned to bottom (Menu) -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:gravity="center" >


</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Scrollable Item below header and above footer -->
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollableContents"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:background="#fff">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="575dp"
                android:padding="7dp" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have searched from some tutorial videos and I find this code for the pdfview:

```
pdfview = findViewById(R.id.pdfview);
        StorageReference storageRef;
        FirebaseApp app;
        FirebaseStorage storage;
        storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        app = FirebaseApp.getInstance();
        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance(app);
        storageRef = storage.getReference().child("uploadPDF");

        storageRef.getStream().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<StreamDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(StreamDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                pdfview.fromStream(taskSnapshot.getStream()).load();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(pdf.this, "Fail :"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

I'm not sure is it I need to open a new empty activity do for the pdfview?

I'm new to Android and I would be grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: If the pdf file is on a server than you first have to download the file to your device before your app can show it to the user. Unclear what you have in mind.

Comment: The code does not have problem, current the pdf file retrieved from firebase need to be download if want to view it, but my expectation is I want to view it directly in the app instead of download it on the phone and view it.